# Android Google Maps v2 not showing Compass and Location Icon

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am not able to show the `compass` icon and the `my location` icon either. I have the code `googleMap.getUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)` and `googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);` but it is not showing on the maps.

```
package com.ctc.weathermap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WeatherMapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weather_maps_main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean enabledGPS = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean enabledWiFi = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!enabledGPS) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(!enabledWiFi) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Network signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
           startActivity(intent);
    }

    initializeMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
}

private void initializeMap() {
    // check if map is created
    if(googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); // creates the map

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Map could not be created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeMap();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    googleMap.clear();
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    marker.title("Current location");   
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));   
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

The rest of the code works such as markers and what not. I have tried putting the code for location and compass in `initializeMap()` but it still does not show up. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Try this..First write this `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` and then write both the codes that you have written..

Comment: ok well that made the `setMyLocationButton` come up thanks! But the compass icon still doesn't show up...

Comment: I think the compass icon will appear only if you rotate the map to not align to north.so please long press on the map and drag it...then i think you will be able to see the compass..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You havent enabled the my-location layer.Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)) for more details

So please do

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

before

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
```

This will make your `setMyLocationButton` come up..

And,the **compass icon will appear only if you rotate the map to not align to north**.

Comment: ok having the `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` makes sense...thanks a lot! the compass shows up now

Comment: It didn't help me.. My class is a Fragment and not an Activity, like this:`public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {` Could that be the reason?

Comment: No @Supercelo That is not the reason. I have using Fragment too but getUiSettings()... helped me.

Comment: I was also not having the location button, but later found it was hiding behind appbar because of incorrect layout_behavior. This comment is for future people who may face the same problem like me.....